# JQuery Flickr file upload not working

Tags: jquery, forms, flickr

I am trying to upload a file using to Flickr using JQuery. I have a form (which works if I dont use JQuery) which I am submitting using the Form Plugin. My code is as follows:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Test Upload</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myForm').bind('submit', function() {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({
            dataType: 'xml',
            success:  processXml
        });
        return false; // <-- important!
    });
});

function processXml(responseXML) {
    var message = $('message', responseXML).text();
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = message;
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<form id="myForm" method="post" action="http://api.flickr.com/services/upload/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="photo" id="photo"/>
<input type="text" name="api_key" id="api_key" value="..snip.."/>
<input type="text" name="auth_token" id="auth_token" value="..snip.."/>
<input type="text" name="api_sig" id="api_sig" value="..snip.."/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
<div id="output">AJAX response will replace this content.</div>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem is I get the following text as a response:

```
<rsp stat="fail">

    <err code="100" msg="Invalid API Key (Key not found)" />

</rsp>
```

even though the file uploads with no problems. This means my div is not updated as it doesnt run the success function. Any one have any ideas.

Thanks

Comment: Can we get a clarification?  You said that the success function is never called but you also said you're getting response text.  How are you getting response text if not through the success call?

Answer (score 2):

See this other thread about uploading files with AJAX:

[How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-to-upload-file-jquery)

I've never tried it, but it seems that you can't get the server response (not easily, anyway)

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to upload a file via AJAX this way.

A pure AJAX file upload system is not possible because of security limitations of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're using **ajaxSubmit**.  That's the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/), right?  Is it possible that the issue is something with that?

Have you tried using [jQuery.post](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post#urldatacallbacktype) instead?

Answer (score 0):

ajax does not work cross-domain.
You can not submit a form using ajax from one domain to another domain.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is - use a proxy.php file on your domain. submit the form using ajax to proxy.php. The code in your proxy.php will submit the form using CURL to flickr. You'll get the CURL code on php.net or many other sites